# Yii2 Select2 also spans original select

Tags: yii2, jquery-select2, dropdown

I'm trying to use `Select2` widget in Yii2 but it's rendering both the Select2 dropdown and the original dropdown.

```
 <div class="homepage-searchbar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="align-middle">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                        <?php
                        $dataCategory=ArrayHelper::map(City::find()->all(),'id', 'city_name');

                        echo $form->field($searchModel, 'city_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                            'data' => $dataCategory,
                            'theme' => Select2::THEME_BOOTSTRAP,
                            'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a city ...'],
                            'pluginOptions' => [
                                'allowClear' => true,
                            ],
                        ])->label(false); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3"> 
                        <?php echo \yii\helpers\Html::submitButton(Yii::t('frontend','Search Now'), ['class' => 'btn btn-default','onclick'=>'return searchRooms()']) ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: screen]

Comment: Do you get some error's in your console browser? do you use select2 from kartik?

Comment: This looks like some styling issues - by default Select2 hides this original select input, but it is still there. You may want to check what styles this input gets - maybe you accidentally override some Select2 styles and make this hidden input visible.

Comment: @Sfili_81 Yes, it's Select2 from kartik. The only warning I get related to Select2 is 

"select2.full.js?v=1537527653:6031 [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'wheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952"

Comment: @rob006 the original Select2.php hasn't been modified. 

In Select2.php: "Html::addCssStyle($this->options, 'display:none');"

Comment: rob006 means: Do you set a display property for your input field for city_id?

Comment: @rob006 - in the minified boostrap css I have: .bootstrap-select.btn-group[class*="span"]{float:none;display:inline-block;margin-bottom:0px;margin-left:0} - however i can't manually set it to none, because it would affect all dropdowns... not sure where else to check :/

Comment: You need to create more precise style which will hide this input in Select2 widget.